# Why is the 4px margin of a fixed div not showing?

Tags: html, css, position, margin

I have a simple fixed position `<div>` which has 100% `width`. It has `4px`  margin all around. However, it does not show the margin on the right hand side. Why?

Here is the code:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div style="position:fixed;height:50px;width:100%;margin:4px;background-color:black;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use this css `body{margin:0;}`

Answer (score 1):

It does have a margin on the right, but you can't see it because it's pushed over the edge of the screen. This is because the width is 100%, the width of the body. The best way to solve it is using `top`, `left` and `right`.

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This way you still have the margin, only in the form of `top`, `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

You should something like below:

```
<div style="position:fixed; left:0; height:50px;width:98%;margin:1%; background-color:black;">
test
</div>
```

And reset the body with following

```
<style>body{margin:0;}</style>
```